# Why running a select query in DB2 throwing an error as string "DECFLOAT"?

Tags: db2

Invalid character found in a character string argument of the function "DECFLOAT".. SQLCODE=-420, SQLSTATE=22018, DRIVER=4.16.53

```
Select VEHICLE_FAMILY from BASE_CONFIGURATION where MODEL_YEAR = 2021;
```

Comment: This is asked often. Did you do any research?  Examine the column datatype of MODEL_YEAR and test your assumptions.

Comment: I didn't post the table definition, which you really should, but my guess would be `MODEL_YEAR` has a character data type, and some values in that column contain data that cannot be converted to a number (e.g. an empty string `''`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Select VEHICLE_FAMILY from BASE_CONFIGURATION where MODEL_YEAR = '2021'
```